# Does MATLAB support named arguments?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default Arguments in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795823/default-arguments-in-matlab)
>   [How to deal with name/value pairs of function arguments in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775263/how-to-deal-with-name-value-pairs-of-function-arguments-in-matlab)

What if you need to create a function with tones of optional parameters. Is there a way to call that functions later on naming passed arguments for readability:

```
foo(123, and=456)
```

Comment: @Andrey: I don't think the linked question is an exact duplicate, though I was sure that we've had this question before; I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719346/specifying-optional-function-parameters-selectively-in-matlab

Answer (score 12):

The comparable way of doing this in Matlab is to have name/value pairs:

```
foo(123,'and',456,'something',[1 2 3])
```

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775263/how-to-deal-with-name-value-pairs-of-function-arguments-in-matlab) on how to deal with them.

Comment: There's a new way: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arguments.html
When using the arguments block for validation, starting with 21a, one can call a function with the `fun(argname=value)` syntax.