# Matlab Error: Function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have written this code. But it shows the error

> Function definitions are not permitted at the prompt or in scripts.

Can anyone help me out with it? what am i doing wrong?

```
function [npv, pvAtPeriod]= npvFlow([100 -5 100],0.04, [1 2 4])
    if isscalar(periods)      
        t = 1:4;
    else        
        t = periods;
    end
    if isscalar(payments)      
        c = zeros(1,length(t));
        c = c+payments;
    else 
        c = payments;
    end
    if numel(c)~=numel(t)
        disp('Error: Payment or period missing.')
        return
    end

    r=rate;

    pvPeriod = c./(1+r).^t;
    npv=sum(pvPeriod);

    pvAtPeriod = [t', pvPeriod'];
end
```

Comment: In addition to the first answer, you have data instead of arguments. Your first line should probably be something like `function [npv, pvAtPeriod]= npvFlow(periods,payments,rate)` (I've guessed the order). If you want default arguments, see [Default Arguments in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/795823/5358968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it states in the error, functions aren't allowed in scripts. We can't see how this script starts, but I'd wager it isn't with `function somefunction()`... See [this documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts-and-functions.html).

In particular:

> Functions are files that can accept input arguments and return output arguments [...]
>   The first line of a function [file] starts with the keyword function.

You must either save your function `npvFlow` in a separate file (on the Matlab path, called `npvFlow.m`) or put the whole script *inside* a function or *starting with* a function. Note that if you change your script into a function then you won't be left with anything in your workspace after running.

---

Your syntax for passing arguments is invalid too (see Steve's comment). If you only ever want those arguments to be fixed, then there is no need for `npvFlow` to be a function and you could also resolve this issue by making the entire thing a valid *script* with no functions!

Comment: Do i need to add it in the path??

Comment: If you save it in the same place as your script then it'll be on the path when you run the script...