# How to run matlab file from command line if it includes function definitions?

Tags: matlab

My matlab files are like:

1. main.m
2. func1.m
3. func2.m
4. func3.m

I want to include the function definitions in the `main.m` file.

`main.m` with function definitions included runs well in GUI. However, it fails in command line. I have to keep the function definitions in separate files. Any clue how to work around this problem?

Here is the command line that I use

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop < main.m > log &
```

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969547/how-to-correct-function-definitions-are-not-permitted-at-the-prompt-or-in-scrip)  [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077938/matlab-error-function-definitions-are-not-permitted-at-the-prompt-or-in-scripts) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667143/matlab-error-message-function-definitions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In MATLAB, can I have a script and a function definition in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363397/in-matlab-can-i-have-a-script-and-a-function-definition-in-the-same-file)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compile the application under Apps->Application Compiler?

Comment: I am not sure because I just followed some guidelines blindly to install MATLAB in Ubuntu