# How to set a default value for my custom function in matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I hope to create such custom function

```
  function addnum(mat,n=numel(mat))
  mat+n
```

I mean I try to add a number into the element of mtrix **mat**,but if I don't give a explicit value for **n**,I hope the **n** will be the number of the mtrix self.

Comment: function addnum(mat)
  mat + numel(mat) ;  can't this work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Arguments in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795823/default-arguments-in-matlab)

Comment: @rahnema1 Oh,actually not,my this default `n` vale linked the first parameter `mat`

Comment: @yode There is no difference. Such a syntax is not acceptable in MATLAB, however Octave accept it.

Comment: @SivaSrinivasKolukula Thanks man,but I hope `addnum(mat,3)` works either,then every element will add 3. :)

Comment: Yes it adds 3 always....as the input is 3.

Comment: @SivaSrinivasKolukula I'm sorry,[that works for you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w04AT.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/795839/7033055),this is what I'm after

```
function addnum1(mat,n)
if nargin<2
    n=numel(mat);
end
mat + n
```